# Stop page element to load

Tags: javascript, dom, console

Is there any way to programatically stop particular page element to load. For example stop a div to load or a praticular image to load from the google chrome console using the dom.

Comment: You will not have access to the element if it's not loaded yet.

Comment: Yeah, you won't be able to access any of the elements in the DOM if it hasn't loaded yet. This sounds like something that should be handled server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to stop an element from loading into the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), since any script running client-side would be a part of the DOM itself. You won't be able to access any of the elements in the DOM if it hasn't loaded yet.

This sounds like something that should happen server side where you could pass data though a template, [like EJS for Node.js](http://www.embeddedjs.com/).

Also keep in mind that even though you can't stop things from being loaded, you can stop them from rendering.

Not saying that this is at all good practice, but you could use:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display="none"
```